# Why is this openmp+mpi code hanging

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp

My code hangs whenever I try running it with many threads. Here's it,

```
double CMpifun::sendData2()
{
    double *tStatistics=new double[8], tmp_time; // wall clock time
    double SY, Sto, header[SZ_HEADER];
    int a_tasks=0, file_p=0;
    vector<myDataType *> d = getData();

    int idx=0;
    opt_k.k=1; opt_k.proc_files=0; opt_k.p=this->node_sz; SY=0; Sto=0;
    std::fill(header,header+SZ_HEADER,-1);

    omp_set_num_threads(4);// for now
    // parallel region
    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(idx,SY,Sto,d,a_tasks,stdout) firstprivate(header) //firstprivate(dat_dim,dat)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num(), cur_idx, cur_k; int N=d.size();
        while (idx<N) { // Assign tasks and fetch results where available
            printf("-------------------------\n%d - 1\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
            #pragma omp critical(update__a_task)
            {
                printf("%d - critique 1\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                if (idx<N) {
                    printf("%d - critique 2\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                    if (a_tasks<node_sz-1){ // available nodes to assign
                        printf("%d - 2.1\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                        MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,TAG_HEADER,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
                        cur_idx=idx; cur_k=opt_k.k; idx+=cur_k;
                        a_tasks+=cur_k;
                    } else {// all nodes assigned. only fetch result
                        printf("%d - 2.2\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                        MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,TAG_RESULT,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
                    }
             }else ;//printf("%d - done task assignment\n", tid); fflush(stdout);

         }

            printf("%d - 3\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
            if (cur_idx<N) {
             printf("%d: cur_idx:%d, opt_k.k:%d, idx:%d, N:%d \n", tid, cur_idx,opt_k.k,idx,N); fflush(stdout);
             if(this->Stat->MPI_TAG == TAG_HEADER){ // serve tasks
                 printf("%d - task %d being assigned to %d\n", tid,cur_idx,(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
                 while (cur_k && cur_idx<N) {
                     printf("%d - T1\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                         header[1]=d[cur_idx]->nRows; header[2]=d[cur_idx]->nCols;  header[3]=cur_idx;
                         header[9]=--cur_k;
                         MPI_Send(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_HEADER,MY_COMM_GRP);
                         printf("%d - T2 %d\n", tid,(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
                         MPI_Send(d[cur_idx]->data,d[cur_idx]->nRows*d[cur_idx]->nCols,MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_DATA,MY_COMM_GRP);
                         printf("%d - T3 %d\n", tid,(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
                         delete[] d[cur_idx]->data;  ++cur_idx;
                 }
             } else if(this->Stat->MPI_TAG == TAG_RESULT){ // collect results
                 printf("%d - result from %d\n", tid,(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
                 while(true){
                     printf("%d - R1\n", tid); fflush(stdout);
                     #pragma omp atomic
                        --a_tasks;
                     double *results = new double[(int)(header[1]*header[2])];
                 MPI_Recv(results,(int)(header[1]*header[2]),MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_DATA,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
                     printf("%d - R2 received result from %d\n", tid,(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
                 delete[] results;
                     if ((int)header[9]>0) {
                         MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_RESULT,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
                     } else break;
                 } //end while
             } // end collect results
         } //end if(loopmain)
         printf("%d - NExt idx: %d\n", tid,idx); fflush(stdout);
     } // end while(loopmain)
    } // end parallel section]

    printf("<<<<<<<<<<<<< MASTER - COLLECTING RESULTS >>>>>>>>>>>> "); fflush(stdout);
    printf("MASTER - pending tasks:%d\n",a_tasks); fflush(stdout);
    while (a_tasks>0) {
        printf("MASTER - wait for slave result request... pending tasks:%d\n",a_tasks); fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,TAG_RESULT,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
        while (true) {
            double *results = new double[(int)(header[1]*header[2])];
            printf("MASTER - wait for result from %d... pending tasks\n",(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
            MPI_Recv(results,(int)(header[1]*header[2]),MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_DATA,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
            delete[] results;
            --a_tasks;
            if ((int)header[9]>0) {
                printf("MASTER - result from slave .. some more\n"); fflush(stdout);
                MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_RESULT,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
            } else break;
        }
    }

    message("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MASTER - terminate slaves >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    for(int i=1;i<node_sz;++i){ // terminate
      MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,TAG_HEADER,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
        printf("MASTER - terminate to signal %d\n",(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
      MPI_Send(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,(int)header[4],TAG_TERMINATE,MY_COMM_GRP);
        printf("MASTER - done terminated %d\n",(int)header[4]); fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("MASTER - bye\n"); fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
```

The Slave function is as follows,

```
void CMpifun::slave2()
{
    double *Data; vector<myDataType> dataQ; vector<hist_type> resQ;
    char out_opt='b'; // irrelevant
    myDataType *out_im = new myDataType;    hist_type *out_hist;    CLdp ldp;
    int file_cnt=0; double tmp_t; //local variables
    double time_arr[3]={}; //1: task wait latency, 2: task set total send time, 3: taskset total process time

    while (true) { // main while loop
        printf("Slave: %d - ........... ready for task......\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
        header[4]=myRank;   MPI_Send(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,TAG_HEADER,MY_COMM_GRP);
        time_arr[0] = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Slave: %d - got master. waiting for task\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,MPI_ANY_TAG,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
        time_arr[0] = MPI_Wtime() - time_arr[0]; // wait for task latency
        if(this->Stat->MPI_TAG == TAG_TERMINATE) {
            printf("Slave: %d - terminate signal received\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
            break;
        }
        printf("Slave: %d - got header. waiting for data\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
        //receive data
        tmp_t = MPI_Wtime();
        while(true) {
            Data=new double[(int)(header[1]*header[2])];
            MPI_Recv(Data,(int)(header[1]*header[2]),MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,TAG_DATA,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
            myDataType d; d.data=Data; d.nRows=(int)header[1]; d.nCols=(int)header[2];
            dataQ.push_back(d);
            file_cnt++;
            if ((int)header[9]) {
                MPI_Recv(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,TAG_HEADER,MY_COMM_GRP,this->Stat);
            } else break;
        }
        time_arr[1] = (MPI_Wtime()-tmp_t); // Total bandwidth time for entire taskset

        file_cnt = dataQ.size();
        tmp_t = MPI_Wtime();
        printf("Slave: %d - got data. processing\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
        while (dataQ.size()) { // process data
            out_hist = new hist_type();
            myDataType d = dataQ.back(); dataQ.pop_back(); // critical section
            ldp.process(d.data, d.nRows,d.nCols,out_opt,out_im, out_hist);
            resQ.push_back(*out_hist); out_hist=0;
            delete[] d.data; delete[] out_im->data;
        }
        time_arr[2] = (MPI_Wtime()-tmp_t); // Total processing time for entire taskset

        // tuma results
        //time_arr[1] /= file_cnt; time_arr[2] /= file_cnt;
        printf("Slave: %d - sending results\n",myRank); fflush(stdout);
        header[4]=myRank; header[6]=time_arr[0]; header[7]=time_arr[1]; header[8]=time_arr[2];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < resQ.size(); i++) {
            header[1]=resQ[i].h_nHists; header[2]=resQ[i].h_binSz; header[9]=resQ.size()-i-1;
            MPI_Send(header,SZ_HEADER,MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,TAG_RESULT,MY_COMM_GRP);
            MPI_Send(resQ[i].hist_data,resQ[i].h_nHists*resQ[i].h_binSz,MPI_DOUBLE,MASTER,TAG_DATA,MY_COMM_GRP);
        }
        resQ.clear();

    } // end main while loop
    message("terminating");
}
```

It hangs after a random number of iterations of the `if (idx<N)` loop. I've been at this for the 2 whole days. Can someone please scrutinize the code and let me in the know on what's causing the problem? All help appreciated in advance

Comment: You code is both way too long, to manually review it (at least for me). It is also incomplete, so we cannot reproduce the problem. Please distill your problem down to a [mcve]. In the process you actually might be able to figure it out yourself. Also you should put more effort in describing how it hangs. Use a (parallel) debugger / correctness analyzer to figure out  where the code hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create unique header tags for every MPI communication pair - it did solve the problem. Is there a way I can delete this question?